# JSignature plugin not working in some versions of IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am using this jquery plugin http://willowsystems.github.io/jSignature/#/about/ to capture signature on browser using pen/finger/mouse.

It works fine will all major browsers even with IE 7,8. As I have included

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/flashcanvas.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

However, it is not working in default IE 8 in Windows XP i.e. version 8.0.6001

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Create issue for your problem here :

https://github.com/willowsystems/jSignature/issues

Maybe it's a bug.

Comment: Unfortunately, they are not active there!